# why を is put after a verb in いまだかつてないスピードで　君のもとへダイブを?

Tags: grammar, parsing, particle-を, song-lyrics

I came across a line of lyrics which goes like this:

> いまだかつてないスピードで　君【きみ】のもとへダイブを.

And I wonder why を is put after ダイブ? I know that を can only be put after the noun to express that the noun is the object. But here ダイブ is used as a verb, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grammatically and syntactically speaking, ダイブ in your sample text cannot be a verb -- there is nothing verb-like about it.

Japanese verbs **require** a verb ending.  In the plain non-past form, that ending is always *-u*, so theoretically, *daibu* might be a verb, with past tense *dainda* and polite form *daibimasu*, for instance.

- However, in such cases, the conjugation ending is pretty much always spelled in hiragana, as we see with verbs like サボる or ググる.  I am not aware of any foreign-borrowed word spelled entirely in katakana and conjugated as a verb all on its own.

Sometimes we can *make* a verb out of such a word, but in that case what we wind up with is technically a verb phrase: we have the noun, and we stick the all-purpose verb する ("to do") on the end.  Examples include things like 勉強【べんきょう】する ("to study", or directly, "to do studying") or ハイキングする ("to hike", or more directly, "to do hiking").

- But then again, your sample text has no form of する after the ダイブ, so we know this way too that ダイブ cannot be a verb.

In modern everyday Japanese, the particle を is used pretty much just to mark the object of a verb.  Objects can be nouns or noun phrases.

- This is one more grammatical clue that the ダイブ here must be a noun.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I understand it grammatically, but then I found that the sample sentence will have no verb.  I thought the translation of this line of lyrics will be something like: 'With a speed I never knew I possessed, I dived straight to where you are'. But how to translate the whole sentence with 'dive' as the noun?

Comment: @Shawmorn, when translating, especially between two languages as widely different in grammar and syntax as Japanese and English, we often have to depart from any strict adherence to the structure and wording of the source text.  This is part of why it can be so difficult to learn any language solely from translation: there will inevitably be some aspects of the language you're learning that just don't fit well into the language you already know.